# Change column width in SharePoint 365, using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, formatting, list-column

I have a several lists containing columns with multiple lines of text. The standard column width is too narrow. I'd like to increase the width using the new column formatting functionality. I've never come across JSON before so ideally looking for something I can copy and paste into the settings for those columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the allitem.aspx, add the script editor web part and add the code below to the script editor web part. It only can work for classic experience.

```
<style>
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='multiplelinename']
{
width : 1000px !important;
}
</style>
```

And if you want to change the width of the multiple lines of text by column formatting, you could refer to the article below.

Use column formatting to customize SharePoint.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#https://docs.microsoft.com/favicon.ico

Comment: Many thanks Amy. We are using the modern experience so unfortunately the script editor option isn't an option, as you say. I had read that article, and what I was hoping for was some JSON that will format the column width. I couldn't find it in those resources, so thought maybe someone here could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for giving your confusion. We cannot change the column width by column formatting. Because the column formatting is to customize how fields in SharePoint lists and libraries are displayed, It cannot change the column width. You could consider using classic experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. It includes a column width and a text color format - remove the color format if you don't want to use it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "green",
    "width": "300px"
  }
}
```